# Is there a common offset value that spans across Kafka partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, server-sent-events

I am just experimenting on Kafka as a SSE holder on the server side and I want "replay capability".  Say each kafka topic is in the form `events.<username>` and it would have a delete items older than *X* time set.

Now what I want is an API that looks like

```
GET /events/offset=n
```

`offset` would be the last processed offset by the client if not specified it is the same as `latest` offset + 1 which means no new results.  It can be `earliest` which represents the earliest possible entry.  The `offset` needs to exist as a security-through-obscurity check.

My suspicion is for this to work correctly the topic must remain in ONE partition and cannot scale horizontally.  Though because the topics are tied to a user name the distribution between brokers would be handled by the fact that the topics are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain event sequence for each of the per-user topics, then yes, you *have* to use one partition per user only.  Kafka cannot guarantee message delivery order with multiple partitions.

The `earliest` and `latest` options you mention are already supported in any basic Kafka consumer configuration.  The specific offset one, you'd have to filter out manually by issuing a request for the given offset, and then returning nothing if the first message you receive does *not* match the requested offset.

Comment: Can you reword the last sentence? I am having trouble following it.